# The button 'Delete Rows" not working in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, rscript, rshiny

I'm making a R shiny app with features such as browse, SpitColumn, and Delete Rows, Replacing values, and Remove columns. Everything works OK except for 'Delete Rows,' which works fine before I add the observeEvent(input$downloadbtn) to the server function.

Could some help me to fix it?

**Overview of the code Basically**
The code accepts a CSV file as input and, depending on the issue, I use the "SplitColumns" and "Delete Rows" and "Replace Values" buttons in the app, however, I'd like to add another button called "Remove Column" now.

'Overview of the app

**csv data**

```
ID  Type   Range
21  A1 B1   100
22  C1 D1   200
23  E1 F1   300
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(DT)
library(tibble)


###function for deleting the rows
splitColumn <- function(data, column_name) {
  newColNames <- c("Unmerged_type1", "Unmerged_type2")
  newCols <- colsplit(data[[column_name]], " ", newColNames)
  after_merge <- cbind(data, newCols)
  after_merge[[column_name]] <- NULL
  after_merge
}
###_______________________________________________
### function for inserting a new column

fillvalues <- function(data, values, columName){
  df_fill <- data
  vec <- strsplit(values, ",")[[1]]
  df_fill <- tibble::add_column(df_fill, newcolumn = vec, .after = columName)
  df_fill
}

##function for removing the colum

removecolumn <- function(df, nameofthecolumn){
  df[ , -which(names(df) %in% nameofthecolumn)]
}

### use a_splitme.csv for testing this program

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn", class = "btn-warning" ),
      uiOutput("selectUI"),
      
      
      actionButton("replacevalues", label = 'Replace values', class= "btn-Secondary"),
      actionButton("removecolumn", "Remove Column"),
      actionButton("Undo", 'Undo', style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
      actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows"),
      textInput("textbox", label="Input the value to replace:"),
      actionButton('downloadbtn', label= 'Download'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL, orig=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$orig <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
  
  output$selectUI<-renderUI({
    req(rv$data)
    selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', choices = names(rv$data))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT(
    rv$data, selection = 'none', server = F, editable = T
  )
  #includes extra column after the 'select column' and replaces the values specified 'Input the value to replace:'
  observeEvent(input$replacevalues, {
    rv$data <- fillvalues(rv$data, input$textbox, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  #Removing the specifield column through select column
  observeEvent(input$removecolumn, {
    rv$data <- removecolumn(rv$data,input$selectcolumn)
  })
  observeEvent(input$Undo, {
    rv$data <- rv$orig
  })
  #Storing the csv file through download button
  observeEvent(input$downloadbtn,{
    write.csv(rv$data,'test.csv')
    print ('file has been downloaded')
  })
  observeEvent(input$downloadbtn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Download Status.",
      paste0("csv file has been downloaded",input$downloadbtn,'.'),
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove the `selection = 'none'` argument from the `renderDT` function so you can select a row, then your button works as expected.